# Cannot connect to MySQL over TCP locally - Connection Timeout - Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: mysql, connection, timeout, ubuntu-9.04

I am running Ubuntu and am ultimately trying to connect Tomcat to my MySQL database using JDBC.

**It has worked previously** but after a reboot the instance now fails to connect.

- Both Tomcat 6 and MySQL 5.0.75 are on the same machine
- Connection string: jdbc:mysql:///localhost:3306
- I can connect to MySQL on the command line using the `mysql` command
- The my.cnf file is pretty standard (Available on request) has bind address: 127.0.0.1
- I cannot Telnet to the MySQL port despite netstat saying MySQL is listening
- I have one IpTables rule to forward 80 -> 8080 and no firewall I'm aware of.

I'm pretty new to this and I'm not sure what else to test. I don't know whether I should be looking in etc/interfaces and if I did what to look for. It's weird because it used to work but after a reboot it's down so I must have changed something.... :).

I realise a timeout indicates the server is not responding and I assume it's because the request isn't actually getting through. I installed MySQL via apt-get and Tomcat manually.

**MySqld processes**

```
root@88:/var/log/mysql#  ps -ef | grep mysqld
root     21753     1  0 May27 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql    21792 21753  0 May27 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-external-locking --port=3306 --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
root     21793 21753  0 May27 ?        00:00:00 logger -p daemon.err -t mysqld_safe -i -t mysqld
root     21888 13676  0 11:23 pts/1    00:00:00 grep mysqld
```

**Netstat**

```
root@88:/var/log/mysql# netstat -lnp | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21792/mysqld
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1926205077 21792/mysqld        /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**Toy Connection Class**

```
root@88:~# cat TestConnect/TestConnection.java

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestConnection {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Connection con = null;

    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      System.out.println("Got driver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql:///localhost:3306",
                "uname", "pass");
      System.out.println("Got connection");

      if(!con.isClosed())
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to " +
          "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");

    } finally {
        if(con != null)
          con.close();
    }
  }
}
```

**Toy Connection Class Output**

Note: This is the same error I get from Tomcat.

```
root@88:~/TestConnect# java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar:. TestConnection
Got driver
                Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)            
        at TestConnection.main(TestConnection.java:14)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2181)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        ... 13 more
```

**Telnet Output**

```
root@88:~/TestConnect# telnet localhost 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

**Iptables**

NOTE: I did have a rule setup in for NAT but I've removed it and the problem persists.

```
root@88:~# iptables -nL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

root@88:~# iptables -t nat -nL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Command used to setup iptables**

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --src 0/0 --dst 88.198.31.14 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

I have since removed the rule this setup for the NAT so unbless there's a side effect to this command it's not relevant.

**UPDATE -I can't ping localhost**

ip a

```
root@88:~/TestConnect# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 16436 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
3: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/void
    inet 127.0.0.1/32 scope host venet0
    inet 88.198.31.14/32 scope global venet0:0
```

ip r

```
root@88:~/TestConnect# ip r
    192.0.2.1 dev venet0  scope link
    default via 192.0.2.1 dev venet0
```

ip rule

```
root@88:~/TestConnect# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

ping -c 1 localhost

```
root@88:~/TestConnect# ping -c 1 localhost
PING localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- localhost.localdomain ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

cat /etc/hosts

```
root@88:~/TestConnect# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
88.198.31.14 88.198.31.14  88 88
```

ifconfig

```
root@88:/var/log/mysql# ifconfig
venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:144432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:153825 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:37896766 (37.8 MB)  TX bytes:28722595 (28.7 MB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:88.198.31.14  P-t-P:88.198.31.14  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Thanks to pQd I think we've narrowed down the error, I need to go read up about what this all means and why localhost isn't ping-able.

Comment: how about giving us result of *iptables -nL* and *iptables -t nat -nL* ?

Comment: cool thing! Can it be that youve lost 127.0.0.1 address from your loopback? Can you give result of *ip a* , *ip r* , *ip rule* , *ping -c 1 localhost* and *cat /etc/hosts* ? What mysql says in /var/log/syslog when it is restarted?

Comment: hey. your loopback is not only down, but also does not have 127.0.0.1 bound to it.

Comment: ifconfig lo up fixed it - yes I am an idiot, not sure what took it down but it all works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you absolutely sure the is no iptables rule preventing tcp/3306 traffic? try this as temporary workaround:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 3306 -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

or maybe your NAT rules to a little bit more than you expect them to do?

ok - your loopback is not only down, but does not have 127.0.0.1 bound to it. add to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

and.. why on earth did you bound it to vnet0? remove it from there.

quick one-time cmd line fix:

```
ip a d 127.0.0.1/32 dev venet0
ip a a 127.0.0.1/32 dev lo
ip link set dev lo up
```

Comment: Hi pQd - I added the output for the commands that you suggested and also tried to telnet after adding your extra rules but still no luck. Do you think there might be something wrong with my interfaces?

Comment: You're onto something! I can't ping localhost, I need to read up about how to add the loop back device or bring it up.

Comment: @gav In /etc/hosts do you have localhost defined?